# Issue with environment variable on Mac OS sierra

Tags: macos, environment-variables, macos-high-sierra

I am seeing a strange problem with the storing of an env in mac os.

I set custom env  in `~/.bash_profile`
export MYENV=user
Then  ran the `. ~/.bash_profile` and then I printed the env using
`printenv` then I can see the MYENV=user in the list.

If I close the terminal and reopen and execute `printenv` then I could not see `MYENV` in the list still  I can see the export MYENV=user in `~/.bash_profile`. It seems strange to me.

I am using **Mac os High Sierra 10.13.6**.
Could some body please tell me what mistake I am doing?

Comment: you are using the wrong file notice `~/.bashProfile` vs `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @BradAllred that was a typo in the question. I corrected it.

Comment: Are you maybe using iterm or some other terminal app besides Terminal.app? I remember having to configure some of those apps to explicitly read .bash_profile when starting a new shell

Comment: Another suggestion that seems to work for some users but not others is to use a file called `.profile`. This is what I use on my mac (had to check because I solved this same problem years ago). See also here: https://superuser.com/questions/320065/bashrc-not-sourced-in-iterm-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Note that *~/.bash_profile* is only run for login shells. From the man page:

`When  bash  is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell
       with the --login option, it  first  reads  and  executes  commands  from  the  file
       /etc/profile,  if  that  file  exists.   After  reading  that  file,  it  looks for
       ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads  and  exe-
       cutes  commands  from  the  first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile
       option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.`

So if you terminal isn't launching the shell with `-l`, `--login` or with `$0` having a leading hyphen it won't be a login shell and thus won't read *~/.bash_profile*. You may need to reconfigure how your terminal launches the shell if you want the shell to read that config script.

On the other hand *~/.bashrc* is always read by an interactive shell. So if you put the export in that script it should do what you expect. It certainly does for me. You replied to Amila that it didn't work for you. So I'd suggest a simple experiment. Open two terminal windows. In one edit *~/.bashrc* and add these two lines:

`echo running .bashrc
export WTF=abc`

In the other window just run `bash`. It should echo that message and `echo $WTF` should print `abc`. Now open a new terminal window. If you don't see that message and the env var isn't present then something is inhibiting reading that config script. Possibly the shell is being run with the `--norc` flag.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are not correct. This is about Terminal.app on Mac OS, and it reads .bash_profile then a new window is opened, not .bashrc, and not on login

Comment: @rje You are only partially correct. What Terminal.app is doing is always launching a login shell by virtue of prefixing the shell name with a hyphen. You seem to not fully understand what is meant by the term "login shell". Also, Terminal.app isn't the only possible terminal. Many people, including myself, use iTerm2 on macOS which provides a richer set of behaviors.

Comment: I was not talking about a login shell. I am fully aware that Terminal.app runs bash as a login shell. I am just clarifying that it runs this when opening a new window, and not on login of the user on the system.

Answer (score -1):

`~/.bash_profile` is executed before the initial command prompt is returned to the user, which means after a new login. Try adding the environment variable to `~/.bashrc` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  but it did not help

Comment: Terminal.app on Mac OS does not read .bashrc but only .bash_profile